# What is this endnote format in BibTex?

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to convert endnote format into bibtex for this [article](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/cmmm/2013/453402/cta/).
I have

```
%0 Journal Article
%T A Novel Automatic Detection System for ECG Arrhythmias Using Maximum Margin Clustering with Immune Evolutionary Algorithm
%J Computational and Mathematical Methods in Medicine
%V 2013
%A Zhu, Bohui
%A Ding, Yongsheng
%A Hao, Kuangrong
%R 10.1155/2013/453402
%D 2013
%U http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2013/453402
%] 453402
%P 8
```

My suggestion

```
% journal article
@article{zhu,
    author = {Zhu, Bohui, and Ding, Yongsheng, and Hao, Kuangrong},
    title = {A Novel Automatic Detection System for ECG Arrhythmias Using Maximum Margin Clustering with Immune Evolutionary Algorithm},
    journal = {Computational and Mathematical Methods in Medicine},
    publisher = {Hindawi Publishing Corporation},
    pages = {8},
    doi = {10.1155/2013/453402},
    year = {2013}
}
```

**What is the article ID, following, and the correct BibTex citing?**

```
    %] 453402
```

Comment: You can use `eid` it is supported by `biblatex` not `bibtex`. Often the `eid` is used for online publication instead of page number.

Comment: The pages field needs to specify the page numbers in the journal e.g. {2--10} or whatever. It is not designed to specify the total number of pages, if that's what the 8 is. Also, you don't want a comma after the names of each author. {Zhu, Bohui and Ding, Yongsheng and...}. And ECG should be protected by curly brackets to ensure capitalisation is not lost {ECG}. If biblatex is not an option, you can put the ID into the note field if you need it.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for pointing out the systematic mistake that I have had in my Bibliography!

Comment: @Guido - Whether or not the `eid` field is processed correctly (or even at all) by BibTeX depends on the bibliography style (bst) file in use, not on BibTeX *per se*. Some newer bibliography styles do provide code for processing the contents of `eid` fields. Unfortunately, the OP hasn't provided information as to which bibliography style is to be used, so we can't tell what will happen if an `eid` field is present in an entry of type `@article`.

Comment: The style is for IEEE.

Comment: @Mico Do you want to investigate a bit further and provide an answer to get another Q off the list?

Comment: @Johannes_B - will do early next week, am currently on vacation in Japan, without access to good Internet resources

Comment: @Mico Wow, get some rest and enjoy your trip. Come back healthy and safe :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Back from Japan... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to using the keyword `and` (rather than commas) to separate names in the `author` field, you should also (i) provide information for the `volume` field and (ii) take care to instruct BibTeX *not* to lowercase certain letters -- such as "ECG" -- in the `title` field. (Observe that volume-related information was included in the endnote-style entry but didn't get transferred to your bibtex-style entry.)

For journals that are published exclusively electronically, it's not common to provide a `pages` field. For sure, neither `pages = "1-8"` nor `pages = 8,` would be quite right. If you truly believe that it might be helpful to your readers to mention that the article fits on 8 printed pages, feel free to provide this information in a `note` field.

It's also not common to mention the company or organization that publishes a journal. If, for some reason, you think that it's important to mention "Hindawi Publishing Corporation", I again suggest using the `note` field for this purpose. (For sure, very few (if any!) bibtex style files recognize a field called `publisher` in entries of type `@article` -- and hence they'll just ignore that field entirely.)

Here's an MWE that includes information both about the publisher and the article length in a `note` field. Personally, I think neither piece of information is useful or important. Do note, incidentally, that the `IEEEtran` bibliography style does *not* print out `doi`-related information. However, a non-empty `url` field will be typeset, so it's a good idea to provide that information.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{zzzz.bib}
@article{zdh:2013,
  author  = "Bohui Zhu and Yongsheng Ding and Kuangrong Hao",
  title   = "A Novel Automatic Detection System for {ECG} Arrhythmias Using {Maximum Margin   
               Clustering with Immune Evolutionary Algorithm}", 
  journal = "Computational and Mathematical Methods in Medicine",
  volume  = 2013, 
  year    = 2013,
  doi     = "10.1155/2013/453402",
  url     = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2013/453402",
  note    = "{Hindawi Publishing Corporation}, 8 pages", 
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{zzzz}
\end{document}
```